# Multiple modular injection angular 1.4.8

Tags: angularjs, module

I am trying to inject afew modules in my angular app.

This works

```
var SMS = angular.module('SMS', ['ui.router']);
```

but this beaks

```
var SMS = angular.module('SMS', ['ui.router','ngProgress']);
```

Error: *Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]*

Comment: make sure you add ngProgress files in your project

Comment: Did you include the `<script>` tag for ngProgress in your `index.html`?

Comment: I have made sure all files are in the project.